# why width not working here?

Tags: css, xhtml

**code**

```
<a href="#" style="width:50px;white-space:normal">Hello how are you</a>
```

**output**

Hello how are you

**Why it's not rendering like this** I need like this.

```
Hello
how 
are 
you
```

**how to achieve output like this without changing in HTML?**

```
<p style="width:165px;height:80px;border:1px solid red">

  <a href="#" style="width:80px;white-space:normal">Hello how are you</a>

  </p>
```

See live example here http://jsbin.com/amozu4

i need link like this

```
Hello
how 
are 
you
```

Comment: Just FYI, the country is spelled 'Italy'

Comment: @waiwai933 that is so not helpful

Comment: @waiwai933: FYI, that "city" is a country.

Comment: What browser are you using? I've tried on Chrome 4, Firefox 3.6, IE8 and it renders as expected (multiple rows).

Comment: @TriLLi - display:block removed, still same result

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<a style="width:40px;display:inline-block;">
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're going to render a list, then make it a list. Even if it means repeating the link for each item.

```
<ul style="list-style:none;">
  <li><a href="#">london</a></li>
  etc
```

The advantage of this is that you can also at any time make it a sentence, by making all li elements `display:inline`.

Comment: of course you can. otherwise it wouldn't make sense to do that, unless it's homework?

Comment: Now why the down-vote, I wonder? +1 because it's the best, and most valid, suggestion made so far.

Answer (score 0):

you can get that using this :

```
a { white-space:normal;}
```

Comment: weird.. its working on Ie7,chrome and FF. do you have other css attached to that page ?

Answer (score 0):

Adding `display:block;width:40px;white-space:normal` works for me.

Comment: `white-space:normal` not necessary